Android Studio parameter hints information not visible for lambda function excution?
enter image description here
As you can see on the image, it is not showing me the hint about parameter passed from the lambda function. when I write code, I have to guess what parameters are being used.
I have tried to turn on
Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion -> show parameter name hints on completion
but it didn't work.

Put the cursor on the Hint section, and Click the Suggest Lamp, you can see Hint enable option, Follow the image


this is really helpful !! Not sure why it is not enable by default...
